# SQL Sub-query to find duplicates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find duplicate values in a table where each field as it's own unique name.

1 Customdata field but each data field is either called SANC or SA ID Number and has it's own unique value.

This query;

```
SELECT CUSTOMDATA, COUNT(*) as count

        from VP_PERSONCUSTDATA

        where CUSTOMDEFNAME = 'sanc'
        group by CUSTOMDATA

having (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Returns all those that have duplicate fields, however, I need to join this query as a sub-query to find everybody with an 'active' employment status.

So 1st table, vp_allperson has the fields i require, specifically 'employmentstatus', but i need it to be linked to the query above which will only show me those with a duplicate customdata entry linked to the customdefname column.

Gosh, i hope this makes sense.

Any suggestions?

I have tried;

```
select a.PERSONNUM

from VP_ALLPERSONV42 a

join VP_PERSONCUSTDATA as b on b.PERSONNUM = a.PERSONNUM

where exists (SELECT CUSTOMDATA, COUNT(*) as count

        from VP_PERSONCUSTDATA

        where CUSTOMDEFNAME = 'sanc'
        group by CUSTOMDATA
        having (COUNT(*) > 1))


and a.EMPLOYMENTSTATUS = 'active'
```

...but with no success.

I'm actually trying to find personnum entries that have duplicate customdata fields. e.g.

Personnum | Customdefname | Customdata (this is where i want to see the duplicates/repeated entries)

Thanks for any input or assistance...

Comment: Maybe you can enter this into http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: Honestly not even sure how to use sqlfiddle yet.. but will check it out. From what i can tell, you create sample tables then play with the queries, correct?

Comment: Exactly - it would be much simpler for everyone to help, if they can look at the tables and play with sql.